# Submit button not in form collection when using MVC Client validation

Tags: jquery, html, form-submit, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have a view with client mvc validation activated and some input type=submit buttons. 
I don't use ajax.

```
<input name="Save" class="btnSave" type="submit" />
```

Fails :

- When i click one of the submit button, the form is submitted, but i have **no trace** of the submit button

Works :

- When i first manually validate the form with javascript (frm.valid() and the form is valid), the submit button **is** in the form collection.
- When i remove all javascript from the rendered html to test and click, the submit button **is** in the form collection

i absolutly need the submit button clicked to be in the form collection

Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you need it in the form collection or more generally in the controller action?

Comment: I need it in the controller action